# mysql next date by day of one field

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

i have a mysql customers table:

```
customer_id | customer_name | creation_date
1           | john          | 2013-09-12 18:34:00
2           | banjo         | 2013-01-11 14:34:00
```

what i would to achieve is to know the closest DAY in the current ot next month that match the creation_date field.

I.E if the current date is 2014-01-20, i would like to have the following result

```
customer_id | customer_name | creation_date       | next_date
1           | john          | 2013-09-12 18:34:00 | 2014-02-12
2           | banjo         | 2013-01-11 14:34:00 | 2014-02-11
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: actually i really have no clue how to attack that

Comment: I can't get your expectaion

Comment: vignesh, what i would like to have is the next date by DAY.

if iv'e created a record on 2013-09-12 i would like to have the next date with the sam day so 2014-02-12

Comment: What happens to 29, 30 and 31 if there are no such dates in current or next month?

Comment: Salman, when i create records i create not after the 28 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work but not tested for edge cases:

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_DATE AS cutoff_date, 
    date_column AS creation_date, 
    CASE 
        WHEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), DAY(date_column)), '%Y-%c-%e') >= CURRENT_DATE 
        THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), DAY(date_column)), '%Y-%c-%e') 
        ELSE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), DAY(date_column)), '%Y-%c-%e') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
    END AS next_date
FROM dates2
```

Results:

```
cutoff_date            creation_date          next_date
-------------------   -------------------    -------------------
2014-01-20 00:00:00    2010-01-01 00:41:00    2014-02-01 00:00:00
2014-01-20 00:00:00    2010-01-10 00:06:00    2014-02-10 00:00:00
2014-01-20 00:00:00    2010-01-19 22:34:00    2014-02-19 00:00:00
2014-01-20 00:00:00    2010-01-19 23:13:00    2014-02-19 00:00:00
2014-01-20 00:00:00    2010-01-20 00:36:00    2014-01-20 00:00:00
2014-01-20 00:00:00    2010-01-20 00:43:00    2014-01-20 00:00:00
2014-01-20 00:00:00    2010-02-15 08:05:00    2014-02-15 00:00:00
2014-01-20 00:00:00    2010-02-25 22:50:00    2014-01-25 00:00:00
```

Comment: Actually, it turns out it is _much_ simpler than this, revising answer in few minutes.

Comment: I would have gone with `SELECT DATE_ADD(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE()), EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_colum)), INTERVAL IF(EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_colum) > EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURDATE)), 1, 0) MONTH)` (or `>=`, depending on whether todays date should result in a date in this or next month).

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the wanted date, than use min/max to get the closest one. Maybe something like that:

```
-- If your stored date is always in year 2013
select CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(creation_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < SYSDATE
            THEN DATE_ADD(creation_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            ELSE DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(creation_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
       END AS next_date
  from customers;
```

This will make your creation_date `2013-09-12` to `2014-10-12`. But if you just want the day maybe this is useful?:

```
-- If your stored date is always in year 2013
select str_to_date(concat(date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m'), date_format(creation_date,'%d')),'%Y-%m-%d') as next_date
  from customers;
```

This should use the current year and month, but change just the day. You can use a `CASE` to check if the difference between the current or the next month is closer.

Comment: ben, thanks! dates are dynamic so that's does not help.

Comment: I've added a new statement to use the current year/month.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, in mysql you can use interval for perticuler increament date like:

```
    select customer_id,customer_name,creation_date,(creation_date+interval 1 year) as next_date  from customer_info;
```

if you want,

- next year then use- (creation_date + interval 1 year)
- next month then use- (creation_date + interval 1 month)
- for perticular day use- (creation_date + interval 5 day)